# deleteByIdAndXXX with Spring Boot JpaRepository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Is there any specific reason why deleteById(id) will throw an EmptyResultDataAccessException if it does not find the record and deleteByIdAndXXX will not return any exception if the record does not exist ?

Is there any alternative way deleteByIdAndXXX could throw an EmptyResultDataAccessException if the record is not found ?

Jonathan.

Comment: Because `deleteById` uses the `Entitymanager.find` before deleting, whereas the other just issues a query which can return an empty result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`deleteById(id)` throws an `EmptyResultDataAccessException` when the entity by id is not found because [it is implemented that way](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L171). Internally `deleteById` does a `findById` and then deletes the fetched entity or throws that exception.

If you want the same behaviour in your delete method you need to implement it manually.